# Not being able to install on device After updating to iOs 12 (NativeScript Vanilla)

Tags: nativescript

The app gets built and it even seems to get installed, but no icon shows up on home screen.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does this happen only on iOS 12 device? Did you try installing the exact same package on other device with iOS 11 or earlier?

Comment: Yes, I did. I will be updating stuff over on the macbook and see if it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Give this a try:**

1. Make sure you run current iOS and Xcode versions
2. Open iTunes and connect your device. Make sure you get to the usual device view that let's you sync etc.
3. Open Xcode and connect your device. Wait for it to finish processing symbol files etc. (Of course make sure, command line tools are installed...)
4. If you're being asked to trust the counterpart device do so.
5. Run `tns platform clean ios`
6. Try building and running your app

Comment: I've done all that. The problem is that it gets installed, but the icon is not displayed. Btw, room for the icon is allocated, I mean, space for the icon is created on the home screen. If I go to Settings>General>Divece Manager I can see the app was indeed installed, because it is listed there. This is very weird.

Comment: I understand the problem. I experienced the same on a reset device. I had to connect it with iTunes. Then everything was fine.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. What I missed doing was to reset the phone. After reset it worked. Thank you all for the help.